# Managing if statements when length of input value is unkown in R functions

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement, lapply

I have two R functions. The **first** one outputs a `data.frame`. The first column of this output is used inside the **second** function.

Specifically, the **second** function takes the argument `long` which can be any numeric vector e.g. `2, 2, 3` of any length. Then, the function outputs a corresponding element from the first column of the first function's outputted `data.frame`.

For example, if `long = c(1, 3, 2)`, then second function assigns the first element of the first function's output to `1`, if `2` the second element of the first function to `2` and so on.

**Q:** Argument `long` can be of any length, how can I mange the required `ifelse` statements? (*see second function below*)?

```
## First function: #==================================

reg <- function(steps, r){

  x <- diag(steps+1)
  data.frame(r^abs(row(x)-col(x)))
}

## Second function: #==================================

foo <- function(long = c(1, 3, 2), r = .5){

g <- reg(max(long, na.rm = T), r)[,1][-1]  ## from the first function

r <- ifelse(long == 1, g[1], ifelse(long == 2) g[2] # . . . ## if. . . how many ifelse needed?
return(r)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a long `ifelse()` function call, you want to use indexing.  In your example, that could be as simple as

```
r <- g[long]
```

A more complicated situation would happen if you need to translate `long` values to indices, e.g. corresponding to something like

```
r <- ifelse(long == 1, g[12], ifelse(long == 2, g[3],  ...
```

Now you need to translate `long` values (1 becomes 12, 2 becomes 3, etc.) first.  How to do that depends to a large extent on whether there are patterns to the translation or not.  Assuming there are no patterns, you just want to set up a named vector:

```
translations <- c("1" = 12, "2" = 3, ...)
```

and use

```
r <- g[translations[as.character(long)]]
```

You need `as.character()` here because names of elements of vectors are always strings.